# Redirection gone wrong in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess file that contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule     ^/?$            index.php     [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^sign-up/?$     sign-up.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^login/?$       login.php   [NC,L]
```

If I go to http://domain.com/sign-up/ with the '/' at the end of the url. It redirects me to the homepage. But when I go to http://domain.com/login/ it works fine.

What is the problem, and how do I solve it?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try it will works.. if not comment

```
RewriteEngine On

#For home page. i.e. index.php
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L]

#For sign-up page. i.e signup.php
RewriteRule ^sign-up$ signup.php [L]

 #For login page. i.e login.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
```

Comment: save your sign-up.php into signup.php

Comment: Also doesn't work, but for the other links it does. So pretty weird

Comment: Still doesn't work, the weird thing is. It worked just fine for a few days until today.

Comment: The problem was the '-' in the sign-up for some reason. So I changed it to register